# Rails 3 - Can Active_admin use an existing user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

Can **Active Admin** use my current **Devise** user model? It already has a column named `admin`, and if it's `true`, I'd like to bypass the Active admin login, when going to `/admin`.

Is this possible?

Current routes:

```
#Active admin
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

#Devise
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
devise_for :users, :path => "account"
```

The rest is basically standard Devise + Active admin

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes you can do that, when [running the generator](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/0-installation.md) skip the user model creation:

```
rails generate active_admin:install --skip-users
```

Then in your `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` :

```
# == User Authentication
#
# Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
# method in a before filter of all controller actions to
# ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
#
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# within the controller.
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin!
```

uncomment `config.authentication_method` and provide your authentication method for your admin, for example:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def authenticate_admin!
 redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user.is_admin?
end
```

Restart your server and It should be working. Also Take a look to [Active Admin Configuration](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/1-general-configuration.md)

Hope this helps.

Comment: where exactly do you place the authenticate_admin! method? I've tried the application controller but I get:

undefined method `authenticate_admin_user!' for #<Admin::DashboardController:0x007fc3a23bce38>

Comment: You'd place this in the config/initializers/active_admin.rb file.

Comment: Or in the application controller.

Answer (score 26):

As stated earlier, you will need to update your `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` to reflect the correct auth method.

Additionally, however, you will want to update the following settings as well:

```
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# to return the currently logged in user.
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

to

```
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

and

```
# This setting changes the path where the link points to. If it's
# a string, the strings is used as the path. If it's a Symbol, we
# will call the method to return the path.
#
# Default:
config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
```

to

```
config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
```

Of course, you don't HAVE to update these (or the method mentioned in the post), and just over-ride the methods elsewhere, but this seems to be the easiest / cleanest approach. You will obviously need to substitute "user" in each setting (`current_USER`) with the name of the model using devise authentication.

I would also recommend updating the following setting as well while you are in there:

```
# This setting changes the http method used when rendering the
# link. For example :get, :delete, :put, etc..
#
# Default:
config.logout_link_method = :get
```

to

```
config.logout_link_method = :delete
```

This last change is required if the default HTTP method used by your devise config is set to  `:delete`, which it is unless you changed it. It matters that they are now synced because if you follow these instructions, you will be using `destroy_user_session_path` which is a path already defined by devise. Otherwise you will get a message stating that [GET] /users/sign_out route does not exist.

Comment: If you won't update current_user_method with current_user, you will probably see a flash with "Comment wasn't saved, text was empty." on ActiveAdmin comment creation, as far as [current implementation provides only empty_text error in case of a failure](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/50d9893ea60993ef72047f072e5a4bc0c4d24b45/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments.rb#L59).

Answer (score 6):

Here's the process if you have already installed ActiveAdmin with default settings, and you want to authenticate users with `User.is_admin` field on your existing model, and remove admin_user table:

Rollback admin_user migrations (if you didn't use `--skip-users` when installing Active Admin):

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141205110842 # create_active_admin_comments.rb
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141205110831 # add_devise_to_admin_users.rb
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141205110820 # devise_create_admin_users.rb
```

Then remove those 3 files.

In routing, remove the line `devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config`

In application_controller.rb, add:

```
def authenticate_admin!
  if current_user && current_user.is_admin
    # fine
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

In active_admin.rb:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin!
config.current_user_method = :current_user
config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
config.allow_comments = false
config.logout_link_method = :get # couldn't get active_admin to sign out via :delete. So I configure devise to sign out via :get.
```

To configure devise to sign out via `:get`, add in devise.rb:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
# And for every occurrence of destroy_user_session_path, remove the option method: delete.
```

Create is_admin migration:

```
rails g migration add_is_admin_to_user is_admin:boolean
```

Edit the migration like so:

```
class AddIsAdminToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :is_admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

And migrate:

```
rake db:migrate
```

If in rails 4, don't forget to add is_admin in permit_params. In app/admin/user.rb:

```
permit_params ....., :is_admin
```

Add rights to admin users, in a console:

```
u = User.find(42); u.is_admin = true; u.save
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

All of what everyone else has said as well as in conjunction with the guide laid out at 
http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/

that adds some additional bits on information if you are choosing to revert back to the option to have a single user model when you have already implemented an admin_user model (ie right now you have a 'user' as well as an 'admin_user' model).

The additional steps included

remove `devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` from routes.rb
copy code from `app/admin/admin_user.rb` to `app/admin/user.rb` (only use what is required)
delete `app/admin/admin_user.rb` (or you will get an [Uninitialized constant error on AdminUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905596/activeadmin-uninitialized-constant-adminuser)) like this guy had (and me as well).