# undefined method `username' for #<AdminUser:0x00000004bb2e58>

Tags: devise, activeadmin

I first installed devise and altered it so I can login with username instead of email.
After that I entered the Activeadmin gem into my gem file.

After that I did a bundle install and rake active_admin:install. 
But after trying to log into the backend /admin/login I see this error message :

```
undefined method `username' for #<AdminUser:0x00000004bb2e58>
```

On this code :

Extracted source (around line #7):

```
4:   <% scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_name) %>
5:   <%= active_admin_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => send(:"#{scope}_session_path"), :html => { :id => "session_new" }) do |f|
6:     f.inputs do
7:       resource.class.authentication_keys.each { |key| f.input key, :input_html => {:autofocus => true}}
8:       f.input :password
9:       f.input :remember_me, :label => t('active_admin.devise.login.remember_me'), :as => :boolean, :if =>  false  #devise_mapping.rememberable? }
10:     end
```

Anyone a idea how to solve this ?
If you need more info just ask.

Roelof

edit : I thought I could solve this by doing this: http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2012/07/29/activeadmin-with-existing-devise-authentication/
But now all the login are failed ( 401) where they without activeadmin they were successfull

Comment: did you resolve this issue?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360787/rails-3-can-active-admin-use-an-existing-user-model

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error and I solved it adding this to my AdminUser model

```
  def login=(login)
    @login = login
  end

  def login
    @login || self.email
  end

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.strip.downcase }]).first
  end
```