# How to install Active Admin somewhere other than "/admin"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to add Active Admin to a Rails app that already has a bespoke CMS and Admin model living at path `/admin`, and which already uses the devise gem, but when I try to run `rails g active_admin:install` followed by `rake db:migrate`, I get this error:

```
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:227:in `eval': Admin is not a module (TypeError)
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:227:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:227:in `register_module'
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:41:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:142:in `new'
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:142:in `namespace'
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:128:in `register'
from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `register'
```

I know it's possible to set a default namespace in the initializer that the install creates, but I wondered if there was a way to pass a default namespace of my choosing in as an option with the install command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 - Can Active\_admin use an existing user model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360787/rails-3-can-active-admin-use-an-existing-user-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - finally figured it out:

I kept the active_admin.rb initializer created when I ran the Active Admin install command the first time, and deleted every other file that it had created. I then added this line to the initializer:

```
config.default_namespace = :my_custom_admin_namespace
```

and ran the install again, skipping the Devise user class (as suggested [here](http://activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html#running_the_generator)), like so:

```
rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
```

I ran my migrations, and I was then able to visit myapp.co.uk/my_custom_admin_namespace. At first I did see an error about an unknown method regarding authenticating users (which makes sense given I skipped creating the user class), so I commented out the following two lines in the initializer:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

and now I can see the dashboard. It's not an ideal setup yet since it's lacking the user class and any authentication, but it's a start.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to get around the problem but if ActiveAdmin can't be successfully installed the first time if the `/admin` namespace already exists, shouldn't it be possible to run the FIRST installation with a flag to change the namespace and avoid this problem?