# Can't login ActiveAdmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Can't login to activeadmin dashboard. I also tried to use hacks founded on stackoverflow but they are not working.
I did default installation to my project using default register script for AdminUser.
My table contain two admins:

```
[#<AdminUser id: 1, email: "admin@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$z5HFkrgIzWxtjO5Fkesz/OornE6y.hKHjVjbUxaC9Nz...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2015-05-25 18:02:11", last_sign_in_at: "2015-05-25 18:02:04", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2015-05-25 18:01:03", updated_at: "2015-05-25 18:02:11">, #<AdminUser id: 2, email: "email@email.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$/y50nKCrOoAuu76kxn5teuaE4MgugTWqhDys6SyDHnH...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-05-25 18:07:54", updated_at: "2015-05-25 18:07:54">]
```

But when I try login nothing happens. Page just refreshing without errors and increase sigin_count value.

My application.rb

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

Comment: check out [ActiveAdmin Authentication](http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#authentication). You need to do some setting in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360787/rails-3-can-active-admin-use-an-existing-user-model) answer will solve your problem